# React Material-UI dropdown menu not working inside Paper

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've copying the instructions on how to use the `Menus` in `Material-UI` docs. I do have the button rendered in my container component that has the `Paper` component but when I click it, the menu is not showing up. Here's the code:

**index.js** - Container component

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: theme.mixins.gutters({
    paddingBottom: 16
  })
});

class ProvidersPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  render() {
    const { classes, providers } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <Paper className={classes.root} elevation={4}>
          <ProviderList providers={providers} />
        </Paper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ProvidersPage.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    providers: state.providers
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(withStyles(styles)(ProvidersPage));
```

**ProvidersList.js** component

```
const styles = theme => ({
  actions: {
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
  title: {
    flex: '1',
  }
});

class ProviderList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  render() {
    const { classes, providers } = this.props;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Toolbar disableGutters>
          <div className={classes.title}>
            <Typography variant="title">
              Providers
            </Typography>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.actions}>
            <ProviderMenu />
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
};

ProviderList.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  providers: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ProviderList);
```

**ProviderMenu.js** - My menu component that has the menus

```
class ProviderMenu extends React.Component {
  state = {
    anchorEl: null,
  };

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
  };

  render() {
    const { anchorEl } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          aria-owns={anchorEl ? 'simple-menu' : null}
          aria-haspopup="true"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          Open Menu
        </Button>
        <Menu
          id="simple-menu"
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
        >
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProviderMenu;
```

Comment: What does this do: `open={Boolean(anchorEl)}`? Shouldn't it just be `open={!!anchorEl}` so as long as `this.state.anchorEl` has a value, it should be open.

Comment: I'm not at a computer to test this, but I'd try taking the handleClose function off the `MenuItems`. It's possible you're catching a bubble effect.

Comment: I was wrong. In this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rp2kyp374), the menu works just fine. I removed the "useless constructors" and I didn't use the `mapStateToProps` function